# Find the Checkbox in Sibling <td> and check it using jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
  $('.answerlabel').click(function()
  {
  $(this).siblings('.answer').find('input:checkbox').attr("checked","checked");
  });
```

There "answer" is one  class and "answerlabel" another  class.Both will be in same .But it is not working.

Any suggestions..
Here is my HTML Code

```
 <table>
 <tr>
 <td class="answer"><input tabindex="5" type="checkbox" name="Dum1_5" id="Dum1_5" value="1"/></td>
 <td class="answerlabel"><label for="Dum1_5" id="Dum1_5_label"><table class="sample"><tr><td><img src="http://bizbox.slate.com/blog/google.jpg"></td></tr><tr><td><b>Product 5</b></td></tr><tr><td>Product Description 5</td></tr><tr><td><b>Price 5</b></td></tr></table></label></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: please show the associated html.

Comment: Please share the html for it as well...

Comment: Hello Fosco and Niklas.. Can you please help me now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this to get the functionality:

```
$('.answerlabel label').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('.answerlabel:first').siblings('.answer').find('input:checkbox').attr("checked","checked");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your support john.. i need it urgently. can you modify it please.Still it is not working for me. :-(

Comment: Ahh, well if you copied an pasted then I have a typo in the class name.

Comment: ha ha ha.. Hmmm i saw that "AnswerLabel" instead of "answerlabel".. changed in my code when copying. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
  $('.answerlabel').click(function()
  {
  var obj = $(this).siblings('.answer').find('input:checkbox');
  if(obj.attr("checked") =="checked")
  {
      obj.removeAttr("checked");
  }else
  {
        obj.attr("checked","checked");
  }
  });
```

This will remove the check from the checkbox when it is clicked again.  It seems to be working:  http://jsfiddle.net/kZNTq/3/